# Add crop- and bleedboxes to an existing PDF

Tags: php, ghostscript

For a project I need to add a crop- and bleedbox to an existing PDF. I have tried a lot of things, but for some reason I do not get it to work. I am not even able to enlarge the PDF to make room for the boxes. I also can't find it on this great site. Is there a function or method in Ghostscript to do such a thing?

Can anyone give me a hint to stear me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this (exactly) with Ghostscript, because GS doesn't simply 'modify' an existing PDF file, when you send a PDF file through GS it completely interprets it and creates a brand new PDF file from the bits.

You could use a pdfmark (executed after the PDF file is complete) to add a crop box and/or a bleed box, but the PDF file you create won't be the same as the one you started with.

Can't you do this with something like pdftk ?

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to do this in the source code of the existing PDF, I'd use the following procedure:

### 1. Unpack the PDF source code with the help of QPDF

QPDF is available here: [qpdf.sf.net/](http://qpdf.sf.net/). It is a commandline tool to achieve *'structural, content-preserving transformations on PDF files'*.

Here, I'd transform the input PDF into an editable PDF which I can easily load and modify in any text editor:

```
qpdf                      \
 --qdf                    \
 --object-streams=disable \
   input.pdf              \
   editable.pdf
```

Note, that there may still be some binary blobs inside the 'editable' PDF (such as font or ICC resources). Therefor your text editor should be able to handle these gracefully.

### 2. Modify the unpacked (editable) PDF in a text editor of your choice

Use a text editor of your choice to add (or modify) `/CropBox` and `/BleedBox` values as you need. (If you use VIm, run it using `vim -b`.)

(I assume that you are well aware of what formal and semantic restrictions the PDF specification imposes to the various `/*Box` values -- otherwise read up a bit about them...)

All PDFs will contain at least one (or more) `/MediaBox` entries. Search for them. For each occurrence of `/MediaBox` add your other box values.

#### 2a. Example:

Assuming, your text editor shows this part of the PDF source code:

```
%% Page 1
%% Original object ID: 11 0
3 0 obj 
<<
  /Contents 5 0 R 
  /MediaBox [
    0
    0
    595   
    841   
  ]
  /Parent 2 0 R 
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F0 9 0 R 
      /F1 10 0 R
    >>    
    /ProcSet [
      /PDF  
      /Text 
    ]
  >>
  /Type /Page 
>>
```

endobj

you could add the following line: `/CropBox [10 200 370 600]` to add a CropBox (which will limit the displayed or printed part of the complete page to the defined area):

```
%% Page 1
%% Original object ID: 11 0
3 0 obj 
<<
  /Contents 5 0 R 
  /MediaBox [
    0
    0
    595   
    841   
  ]
  /CropBox [10 200 370 600]
  /Parent 2 0 R 
  /Resources <<
    /Font <<
      /F0 9 0 R 
      /F1 10 0 R
    >>    
    /ProcSet [
      /PDF  
      /Text 
    ]
  >>
  /Type /Page 
>>
```

endobj

and save it as *'edited.pdf'*.

Note, that after saving this modified PDF it will be 'corrupted' in the sense that the additional line will have invalidated the PDF's *table of contents* (that is, its `xref` section), and many PDF readers will not be able to open it without error or warning messages popping up.

Therefor, a last step is needed:

### 3. Re-pack and repair the edited PDF with the help of QPDF

```
qpdf edited.pdf modified.pdf
```

You'll see a warning from QPDF telling you that the input PDF needed some repair of its `xref` section...